# Tcl regexp: How to check if variable contains number?

Tags: regular-expression, tcl

Below is my tcl script for checking if there is any 0-9 number find in the variable.

```
    set a "abc"

    if {[ regexp {[0-9]*} $a ]} {
       puts "Found number in $a"
    } else {
       puts "Doesn't find number in $a"
    }
```

But when I run it, it reports "Found number in abc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using a regular expression that means "match 0 or more numbers". The string `abc` matches 0 numbers, so you get a positive result. Just remove the `*` ("0 or more") and it should work as expected:

```
set a "a2bc"

if {[ regexp {[0-9]} $a ]} {
        puts "Found number in $a"
} else {
        puts "Doesn't find number in $a"
}
```

Comment: @Fisher If this (or another) answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

In a regular expression, `*` means "zero or more of the previously specified character or class".  So you are looking for any string with zero or more numerical characters.  Which matches everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glob-style patterns to solve this as well without needing the power of regular expressions:

```
if {[string match {*[0-9]*} $a]} { ...
```

See [`string match`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) documentation.